# FuelPHPのORMモデルを使う場合、トランザクション処理は可能か？

Tags: php, fuelphp, orm

FuelPHP(1.7)でご質問させてください。
ORMモデルを利用したDB操作の一連のロジック(基本的な)を作成する場合
トランザクション処理はどのようにして実装すればよろしいのでしょうか？

クエリビルダであれば

```
$db = Database_Connection::instance();
$db->start_transaction();

try {
  //
  // データベースの更新処理など
  //
  $db->commit_transaction();
catch (\Exception $ex) {
  $db->rollback_transaction();
}
```

と実装すればよさそうですが。。。

調べてもいまいちヒットしないため
ご質問させて頂きます。

ご教授のほど、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: APIドキュメントを見ると `Orm/Model->save()` メソッドの第２引数にてトランザクション使用の有無を指定できるようですが、これとは別のお話でしょうか？ http://fuelphp.com/api/classes/Orm.Model.html

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
たしかに第２引数にフラグがありますが、
たとえば
Aテーブルの更新、
Bテーブルの更新
という処理で、Bの更新処理でエラーが発生した場合、
Aの更新とBの更新をrollbackしたいです。

その場合、saveの第２引数のトランザクションフラグで実現可能かどうかしりたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FuelPHPには詳しくないことはあらかじめお断りしておきます。
さて、FuelPHPの公式フォーラムに以下の質疑を見つけました。

[ORM Transactions - FuelPHP » Forums](http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/12563)

質問：

> Is it possible to use transaction with ORM. I need to do a "select ... for update" transaction but can't really find a way to do this with ORM.

回答：

> ORM doesn't have any built-in transaction methods, other then on save(), to put related updates into a transaction.
>
> You can wrap your ORM calls into a transaction manually using http://bin.fuelphp.com/snippet/view/oA

回答者は FuelPHP のプロジェクトリーダーである [Harro Verton](http://fuelphp.com/about) 氏です。

この質疑があったのが2013年9月で FuelPHP 1.7 がリリースされる少し前のようです。どこまで現状でも有効な話なのかまでは確認していませんが、上記の回答によると単純に明示的にトランザクション開始メソッドとコミットメソッドでラップしてくれということのようです。
上記回答のリンク先に貼られていたスニペットは僅かに以下のようなものでした。

```
<?php

$db = \Database_Connection::instance(\Model_Yours::connection(true));
$db->start_transaction();

// do your stuff

// or rollback_transaction();
$db ->commit_transaction();
```

ですので、考え方としては質問に挙げられていた方法で差し支えなさそうに思われます。
もちろんこのときには `\ORM\Model->save()` ではトランザクションスイッチを無効にしておく必要があるものと思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
仮のコードで表すと
(モデルはOrm\Model)
`$db = Database_Connection::instance();
$db->start_transaction();

try {
  
   $user = Model_User::find(1);
   $user->point = 2;
   $user->save();

   $point = Model_Point::find(1);
   $point->totalpoint = 2;
   $point->save();

  $db->commit_transaction();
catch (\Exception $ex) {
  $db->rollback_transaction();
}`

のようにすればいいということですね。
リレーションがあった場合どうなるかなど
これから実際にテストで動作検証してみます。

ありがとうございました